# Matching tuples with multiple possible values

Tags: pattern-matching, rust, tuples

As tuple matching with ranges works, I hoped something similar would also work with alternatives:

```
match x {
    (1, 1) => println!("A"),
    (1, 2 ... 3) => println!("B"),   // ranges work
    (2 | 5, 4 | 6) => println!("C"), // this doesn't
    _ => println!("D")
}
```

Is there an elegant solution to this or does one have to either "unroll" the alternatives or resort to chained `if`/`else if` instead of pattern matching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since [Rust 1.53](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1530-2021-06-17), pattern matching was extended to allow nested `|` patterns. So the original presented example compiles as is in that regard ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c12ddb12f80b77d438cc5b043f9e1779)):

```
match x {
    (1, 1) => println!("A"),
    (1, 2..=3) => println!("B"),
    (2 | 5, 4 | 6) => println!("C"),
    _ => println!("D")
}
```

<sup>(`...` for inclusive ranges were deprecated in 2021 Edition in favor of `..=`)</sup>

Answer (score 22):

Alternatives are not part of the syntax for patterns; `a | b` is not a pattern. Alternatives can only be used to combine patterns in a `match` arm (they are not available in `if let` and `while let` expressions either).

A workaround is to use guards:

```
match x {
    (1, 1) => println!("A"),
    (1, 2 ... 3) => println!("B"),
    (a, b) if (a == 2 || a == 5) &&
              (b == 4 || b == 6) => println!("C"),
    _ => println!("D")
}
```

Guards are arbitrary expressions (that must evaluate to a `bool`), so they can call functions.

```
match x {
    (1, 1) => println!("A"),
    (1, 2 ... 3) => println!("B"),
    (a, b) if [2, 5].contains(&a) &&
              [4, 6].contains(&b) => println!("C"),
    _ => println!("D")
}
```

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt But if you also need `(5, 4)` and `(2, 6)` to match, it quickly becomes very verbose.

Comment: @Kroltan: My code above prints `C` for `(2, 4)`, `(5, 4)`, `(2, 6)` and `(5, 6)`...