# Or-operator in matching sub patterns

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

The Rust [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html) says not much about the `|`-operator for pattern matching. It only gives one example:

```rust
let x = 1;

match x {
    1 | 2 => println!("one or two"),
    3 => println!("three"),
    _ => println!("anything"),
}
```

Contrary to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39160179) of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39159857), I noticed that the following compiles:

```rust
struct S(E, usize);

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum E {
    P(u8), Q(u8)
}

fn main() {
    let x = S(E::P(1), 10);
    if let S(E::P(..) | E::Q(..), _) = x {
        
    }
    
    let y = E::P(2);
    match (y, y) {
        (E::Q(..), E::P(..) | E::Q(..)) => {
            
        }
        _ => {}
    }
}
```

In that particular question, integers were matched, not values of enum type. Integers implement the std::ops::BitOr trait, so there would be a conflict there for sub patterns.

My questions are:

1. Is this a feature? Why does it compile? Why does it seem to work?
2. What are the limitations of this feature? (e.g. type must not implement BitOr or similar)
3. What is the feature called? What is the AST node used to implement the feature called? Even the name of the type of the AST node in the compiler implementation would be a better name to use in discussion than calling it the "`|`-operator", which is very vague.

Comment: I've added an answer to the linked Q&A to address the discrepancy with the current behavior.

Comment: "Integers implement the std::ops::BitOr trait, so there would be a conflict there for sub patterns." There's no conflict. Patterns are not expressions and a match arm is comprised by a pattern, so `|` is always pattern alternation. See e.g., https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1b8e31eb086e8c91195f40052107d954

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a feature? Why does it compile? Why does it seem to work?

Before Rust 1.53, `|`s were only allowed at the top-level of a match arm, but since then they were expanded to be allowed in nested patterns. So what you see is working as intended; just the linked Q&A was out-dated.

---

> What are the limitations of this feature? (e.g. type must not implement BitOr or similar)

On the contrary, this does not use the `BitOr` operator and thus will work on any type that can be matched to multiple values. Remember pattern matching employs *structural* equality, not *value* equality. And because of that, the pattern `1 | 2` will match either `1` or `2`, while if it used `BitOr` then it'd only match `3`.

Feature-wise, this is fairly unlimited:

> *Or-patterns* are patterns that match on one of two or more sub-patterns (e.g. `A | B | C`). They can nest arbitrarily. Syntactically, or-patterns are allowed in any of the places where other patterns are allowed, with the exceptions of `let`-bindings and function and closure arguments.  - [Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html#or-patterns)

---

> What is the feature called? What is the AST node used to implement the feature called? Even the name of the type of the AST node in the compiler implementation would be a better name to use in discussion than calling it the "|-operator", which is very vague.

The original [RFC 2535](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2535-or-patterns.md) was simply called "or-patterns" and that is reflected in the reference documentation. Not sure about the name of the AST node, but the [Pattern grammar](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/patterns.html) in the Rust Reference simply has the `|` chain as directly part of the `Pattern` production and other types of patterns are deferred to `PatternNoTopAlt` or `PatternWithoutRange`.

Comment: Small nitpick: `1 | 2` is `3`, not `0`.

Comment: @Jmb woops! Was thinking `&`